# How to make curl call to docker container running inside another docker container?

Tags: docker

My application is spring-boot app run on port 8080.
Below is sample script. One part is from gitlab-pipeline and another two are before and run script.

Inside Gitlab pipeline:

```
stages:
  - performance

#Run performance test
load_performance:
  stage: performance
  when: manual
  before_script:
    - source ./scripts/gitlab/perf-test/before-script.sh
  script:
    - echo "Running load test"
    - source ./scripts/gitlab/perf-test/run_gatling.sh
  after_script:
    - ls -ltra ./scripts/performance-test/gatling
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "./scripts/performance-test/gatling/results"
    expire_in: 1 week
    when: always
```

before-script.sh: This script download image of gatling and my app and start it in detached mode.

```
LOCALHOST="host.docker.internal"
BASE_URL="http://${LOCALHOST}:8080"


echo "Pulling Gatling image"
docker pull denvazh/gatling


echo "Start my-service2"
starttime=`date +%s`

docker run --ulimit nofile=65536:200000 -itd -p 8080:8080 --name my-service \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v $DIR:/opt/app \
gcr.io/com-gcr/my-service-java:jdk-X.X.X_X \
/bin/bash -c "cd /opt/app && ls -ltra && source .envrc \
          && ./gradlew clean bootRun"
```

run_gatling.sh: this script check my-service is up or not. If it is up then start gating test.

```
sleep 5
docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' my-service

while ! curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/health ## this condition always fail but on local it passes after 1-2 minutes
do
    echo "waiting on my-service to up"
    docker logs --tail=10 my-service
    sleep 30
done

echo "my-service up. It took $(($(date +'%s') - starttime)) seconds."



echo "Starting test:"
starttime=`date +%s`

docker run -it --rm -v $DIR/scripts/performance-test/gatling/conf:/opt/gatling/conf \
-v $DIR/scripts/performance-test/gatling/user-files:/opt/gatling/user-files \
-v $DIR/scripts/performance-test/gatling/results:/opt/gatling/results \
-e JAVA_OPTS="-Dduration=$DURATION -DbaseUrl=$BASE_URL -DmaxRequest=MAX_REQUEST" \
denvazh/gatling -rd performance_tests

docker stop my-service
docker rm my-service


echo "Test complete. It took $(($(date +'%s') - starttime)) seconds."
```

Comment: `localhost` in Docker usually means "this container", so if a second container is literally doing `curl http://localhost...` it's not reaching the application container.  Can you provide some of the actual code in this setup?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze I have added pseudo code. My code is working on a local machine. On localhost port 8080, all requests are forwarded to container port 8080 but this is not working inside gitlab runner.